# LinearLayout with Imageview and Listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview, android-linearlayout, composite

I'm working on an app where I want the logo left justified and then a list of categories on the right side.  So what I have is the logo in an image view which is in the Linear Layout and then I add a ListView to the LinearLayout too so they can be on the same activity.  When I try to run it, I get a stopped unexpectedly error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Commands.setText("Commands");
    LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);

    ImageView Logo = (ImageView)findViewById(0x7f020000);
    Logo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_myplaces));

    ListView Cats = new ListView(this);

    String Categories[] = new String[3];
    Categories[0] = "Hardware";
    Categories[1] = "Language";
    Categories[2] = "Libraries";
    ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0, 2, Categories);

    Cats.setAdapter(list);
    LL.addView(Logo);
    LL.addView(Cats);
    setContentView(LL);

}
```

Any help, I'm really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think the problem is, you haven't called setContentView() in your onCreate().

So obviously, Android doesn't know where to look for `ImageView` with that id and you will run into Null Pointer most probably.

Add `setContentView()`  to your `onCreate()` before thsi line,

```
 ImageView Logo = (ImageView)findViewById(0x7f020000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create layouts in Android is to create a layout in a res/layout folder in xml and inflate it when you load your onCreate method.  For example this xml might accomplish what you are looking for:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/(name for image view)"
      android:layout_width="(some size)"
      android:layout_height="(some size)"
     >
    </ImageView>

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/(name for list view)"
      android:layout_width="(some size)"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
<LinearLayout>
```

You should be able to find a lot tutorials on creating layouts with xml.